# Build non-http socket based service with undertow

Tags: java, telnet, undertow

I have a full-stack http based framework uses undertow as network layer. Now I want to add an embedded telnet service into the framework to allow CLI for admin. I am wondering if there is a way to build the telnet server based on undertow, kind of like the [this netty based telnet server](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/telnet/TelnetServer.java)

Comment: why not use http for admin too?

Comment: We have the needs of providing console based admin tool